# Modal View Full Screen not returning to view properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, modal-dialog, presentmodalviewcontroller

I've been having trouble trying to create a full screen modal view on an iPhone application, but when I present it if it is in landscape, the view will be in one small portion of the screen.  If it appears, and then you rotate it to a different orientation, it will either be a white screen, or a shrunken window in a corner.  Here's how I call it:

```
bookmarks.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
bookmarks.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:bookmarks animated:YES];
bookmarks.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,460);
```

Comment: are you sure you wanted to use bounds and not frame for your bookmarks view?

Comment: Changing between the two didn't make any difference in the view, they both returned to a white screen. The quick fix I did with this was convert it all to a navigation stack and push and pop views as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was replacing where modal views are called with pushes on the navigation stack. It took a bit longer because I had to restructure a tab I was working on with a navigation controller instead of a regular view controller.